Typesetting metapost labels horizontally into a transformed picture
I want to produce a sequence of [successive] drawings from a single program—to illustrate the successive steps in some process—where every next picture is the previous plus a little extra something.  I want to write the text of the program describing the final result (last picture in the sequence) more or less once but shipout at key points along the way, something broadly as the following:
% draw something
charcode := 1;
shipout currentpicture;
% draw some more
charcode := 2;
shipout currentpicture;
% ...

Now, it's a bit more complicated than that because I want every drawing somewhat transformed and decorated but I am able to do this with an exportit macro I defined which takes care of the decoration:
% draw something
exportit(currentpicture, 1);
% draw some more
exportit(currentpicture, 2);
% ...

What I cannot figure out is the label handling so I am asking here in case someone knows and can suggest of a pattern or existing functionality I can use.
The problem is that I want the labels to always be horizontal, as if typeset on lines parallel to the page's top and bottom sides.  This means that I cannot add the labels to the drawing as described above.  If I do, the labels end up at the right places but the label text is transformed (rotated, shifted, etc.) with the transform of the picture.  So the labels need to be typeset last by the macro and not in the drawing commands before calling the macro (typeset at their already transformed positions, of course).
But how to pass this information to the macro?  After struggling a bit, I figured out one way ot doing it by adding text parameter with the labels that can be scantokens'd somewhat like the example at the end but this is quite ugly and fragile, I think (although it seems to so far work).
I am open to any suggestions on how to achieve the above in a better, more native/metapost-y way?  For example, typeset the labels before calling the macro but inverse-trasnformed somehow so that when the macro transforms the picture to shipout the transform it (the macro_ applies undoes the one applied to the labels so they end up horizontal?  That's also not optimal because the transform is different for every step (since it depends on the bounding box of the changing picture); I can get around that with a second macro to compute the transform but I find this about equally ugly.
input TEX;

% top level definition of points, paths, etc, no drawing yet
z1 = ...;
p0 = ...;

% Labels that will be typeset
string s[];
s0 = "$A$";
s1 = "$B$";

% p, seq, and scanned are the picture, its number, and the
% labels to be typeset into it, respectively.
vardef exportit(suffix p)(expr seq)(text scanned) =
  picture pic;
  % make pic from p by transforming, decorating, etc.
  alpha := ...;
  pair shift;
  shift := ...;
  ...;
  % Add the free text.
  picture from_scanned;
  from_scanned = image (
    scantokens(scanned);
  );
  addto pic also from_scanned;
  charcode := seq;
  shipout pic;
enddef;

% Draw some stuff.
draw ...;
s5 := "dotlabel.llft(TEX(s0), z1 rotated alpha shifted shift);";
exportit(currentpicture, 1, s5);

% Draw some more stuff.  Keep all the labels from s5 plus add some extra.
draw ...;
s6 := s5 & "dotlabel.llft(TEX(s1), z4 rotated alpha shifted shift);";
exportit(currentpicture, 2, s6);


It's hard to answer this question without a more complete example to play with, but I can at least suggest a simpler, alternative approach that might work better.
There is nothing magical about beginfig and endfig -- they are just macros -- so you might consider putting a loop around them to output multiple versions of your drawing.
Here is a toy example:
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.eps";
for i=1 upto 3:
  beginfig(i);
    path c; c = fullcircle scaled 100;
    if i > 1:
      c := c yscaled 3/4;
      if i > 2:
        c := c rotated 20;
      fi
    fi
    draw c;
  endfig;
endfor
end.

Compiling this with mpost produces three .eps files that look like this:









Thanks, I've added a full example at https://github.com/giik/mpost-incremental if you'd like a look. As I mentioned, it's about building a figure and exporting it along the way at various stages. I was able to make it work and I can live with the current state, it just feels clunky so wanted to see what improvements more experienced folks may suggest (so please let me know if you have any).  Cheers!
